# Change ARR affinity property from General Settings with Azure Devops pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I'm trying to modify the "ARR affinity" (clientAffinityEnabled) property in App Service General Settings with a pipeline task but it doesn't work, the value doesn't change.
This pipeline works OK with other General Settings properties.

Another approach to solve this?

Azure DevOps pipeline task:

```
  - task: AzureAppServiceSettings@1
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: XXXXXXX
      ResourceGroupName: XXXXXXX
      appName: XXXXXXX
      generalSettings: |
        [
          {
            "clientAffinityEnabled": false
          }
        ]
```

Comment: Are you not managing the creation and management of your cloud resources via an infrastructure-as-code tool like Bicep or Terraform? Because that would be the recommended approach.

Comment: @deathrasher Is there any update about this ticket?

Answer (score 0):

Test the same settings in the AzureAppServiceSettings task, I can reproduce the same situation. It seems that the AzureAppServiceSettings task is not able to update the ARR affinity value.

For a workaround, you can change to use Azure CLI Task to run the Azure CLI: [az webapp update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-update) to update the ARR affinity value.

For example:

```
steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Azure CLI '
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: xx
    scriptType: ps
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: 'az webapp update  --name xx --resource-group xx --client-affinity-enabled false'
```